# What does length(Tr) != nrow(X) mean?

Tags: r, match, matching, propensity-score-matching

Rookie coder here so please bear with me. Trying to run a propensity score match in R for a medical paper where I am trying to compare a medical treatment across two groups.

```
#Propensity score model
glm1 <- glm(Tr ~ X, family = binomial, data = mydata)
summary(glm1)

#Average Treatment on the treated effect
rr1 <- Match(Y = Y, Tr = Tr, X = glm1$fitted)
summary(rr1)
```

When I run the Match function, this error comes up:

> Error in Match(Y = Y, Tr = Tr, X = glm1$fitted) : length(Tr) != nrow(X)

Not sure what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: It means `length(glm1$fitted)` is unequal to `nrow(X)`.  Probably you have missings that are being deleted during regression.

Answer (score 3):

`Match()` does a check to make sure the treatment variable `Tr` has the same number of units as the covariates `X`. In this case, `Tr` corresponds to your treatment variable, which you also called `Tr`, and `X` corresponds to the propensity scores you supplied as `glm1$fitted`. These two vectors do not have the same length, and that is the problem you are observing.

First, I must ask whether you have created separate variables `Y` and `Tr` *outside* your dataset `mydata`. If not, then you are supplying empty variables to `Match()`. If so, check the length of `Tr` and `glm1$fitted` by running `length(Tr)` and `length(glm1$fitted)`. These must be the same for `Match()` to work. If these are not the same length, you need to figure out why.

One reason, as mentioned by @jay.sf in the comments, is that there is missing data in your covariate `X` that you used as the predictor in the logistic regression model `glm1`. If there are missing values, any rows with missing values will be deleted before running the logistic regression, so you will only get propensity scores for the observations with no missing values.

If you have missing values and are trying to do propensity score matching, consult with a professional statistician if you are not familiar with coding in R as this requires advanced training to deal with.